# Configure git-remote-dropbox

Tags: git, dropbox

I read about [git-remote-dropbox](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox) features which connects Git with Dropbox.

I was wondering how to setup this on Windows?

1. Where to I have to initially create the git repository via `git init`?
   In my Dropbox workspace (some kind of %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox)? Or any other folder?
2. What is meant with and where are these locations?

   > Save your OAuth token in ~/.config/git/git-remote-dropbox.json or ~/.git-remote-dropbox.json.
3. How do I clone the repo?
   `git clone "dropbox://path/to/repo"` or is it some kind of
   `git clone "https://www.dropbox.com/path/to/repo"` where `repo` is the folder containing the `.git` folder?

Comment: @clu can you help with the answer?

Comment: @clu And it would be helpful to extend the help in [README](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox) - especially for newbies to git.

Comment: or maybe   @fwenom ?

Comment: or maybe  @merlin2011 ?

Answer (score 0):

When I set up git-remote-dropbox I got an error when trying to push to the remote:

```
Error: missing config file: C:/Users/<user>/.config\git\git-remote-dropbox.json
```

Once I put the config file in this folder it started working.